# Display ErrorMessage into my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display my error message that exist in my model to my view .
there is my model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The UserName is required.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Password is required.")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information, there's a ton of reasons this could happen. Can you also post the relevant part of the View?

Comment: what does you view and action method look like?

Comment: thank you.the problem was resolved.

Comment: I should add some code to my controller(If(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   Return View(model);
})

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` in your view and that your controller is structured similar to

```
If(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   Return View(model);
}
```

Data annotations only will display an error if you structure your controller and front end appropriately to display the message upon failure.